# How do i make image view be directly left of Label

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have label with text that can change, changing width label as well, the label is centered.
But now I want to place a picture left of the label.

```
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(0,screenSize.height*0.3f,screenSize.width*0.2f,screenSize.width*0.2f)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[picture setFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x - screenSize.width*0.1f,label.frame.origin.y,screenSize.width*0.1f,screenSize.width*0.1f)];
```

Obviously this doesn't work the way I wanted since origin.x of label is 0.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using autolayout?

Comment: all this is happenning within a scrollview.
As I was trying to make scrollview work all tutorials suggested unchecking autolayout.

Comment: Then the tutorials are wrong. Learning to configure a scroll view under auto layout is an important iOS programming skill.

Comment: I see, ill invest time into learning to work with Autolayout then. 
Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Wain why use autolayout for this? he could just move the imageview by code